# The number of 1’s that are in the same position in Num and Parity Mask

Tags: c, bit, parity

I am giving a function to write as part of my program that takes as input a
short integer num, and a short integer parity mask. The function then return the
number of 1’s that are in the same position in num and in the parity
mask. for example, if you enter num as `0x8` and parity mask as `0x9` then it return 1. (since `0x8 = 00001000` and `0x9 = 00001001` so they both have a 1 at position 3).

I have looked everywhere online trying to find a simple way to implement it but couldn't find anything similar to it.

Could someone please explain to me how to write this function or give some suggestion on how to start?

Thank you

Comment: Use a bitwise AND to combine the two numbers, then count the number of 1 bits in the result.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109023/how-to-count-the-number-of-set-bits-in-a-32-bit-integer for how to count the bits in a number.